# Deployed a JAXWS application shows up as blank page in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

Deployed a JAXWS application in tomcat , but the service shows a blank page with no errors in tomcat.

http://{localhost}:8080/SFOD-WS/storesurveytemplate

// when i check for my service deployed , no erros with blank page.

What could be the issue ? why is my deployed service not showing showing up??

Comment: is there any error in the log while deploying ?

Comment: also, the logs should show the binded endpoint url. Make sure is the correct one.

Comment: there are no errors while dpeloying. sorry but what is meant by binded endpoint url?

Comment: How have you verified the service was deployed? Do you have log output that says so? Maybe something from `WSServletContextListener`?

Comment: Once a server startsup, i find the war exploded to its package. Will that confirm if my application is deployed successfully??? Could please suggest how could I confirm if my application is deployed in tomcat and weblogic??